# Suspicious processes when running ps -Af

Tags: linux, security, centos7, malware

Can anyone explain for me what to do if i see this on my PS list?!

```
apache   23687  2388  5 12:40 ?        00:00:02 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
postfix  23830  1971  0 12:40 ?        00:00:00 cleanup -z -t unix -u
apache   24167     1  0 Jun13 ?        00:00:17 /tmp/wwrr10/wwrr10
apache   24235     1  0 Jun13 ?        00:00:17 /tmp/wwrr/wwrr
apache   24276     1  0 Jun13 ?        00:00:17 /tmp/wwrr20/wwrr20
apache   25509     1  0 Jun11 ?        00:00:30 /tmp/sdvvrtw/sdvvrtw
apache   25546     1  0 Jun11 ?        00:00:30 /tmp/sdvvrtw10/sdvvrtw10
apache   25576     1  0 Jun11 ?        00:00:31 /tmp/sdvvrtw20/sdvvrtw20
apache   29100     1  0 Jun15 ?        00:00:03 /tmp/bgbh/bgbh
apache   29120     1  0 Jun15 ?        00:00:03 /tmp/bgbh10/bgbh10
apache   29140     1  0 Jun15 ?        00:00:03 /tmp/bgbh20/bgbh20
```

Comment: Are you the one that started up the HTTP server? If so this looks relatively normal. Otherwise you've got a problem on your hand.

Answer (score 3):

Your Apache installation may be using prefork. This mpm spawns a process per request. So if you are under a bit of load and nowadays knowing how many concurrent requests some browsers send, that list of process is quite usual. if this is the case it can be a misconfiguration in your php files making them behave incorrectly.
You can also try to reducing the number of of clients in the httpd.conf file.